# Weird error when using datatool's `\DTLaddall` in a `\DTLforeach`

Tags: tex-core, database, datatool

Given `test.csv` containing:

```
donor,core,non-core
Norway,137.6,111.4
The Netherlands,116.6,85.8
```

and `data-problem.tex` containing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{contrib}{test.csv}

% add "total" column
%\tracingmacros=1
\DTLforeach{contrib}{\contribC=core,\contribNC=non-core}{%
\DTLaddall{\contribT}{\contribC,\contribNC}}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
(e:\Documents\Anthropology\Paper\data-problem.aux) ( FP-EQ? ) ( FP-ADD )
Runaway argument?
\relax \fi \ifnum \@dtl@tmpcount  
                   \par 
l.11 

[1] (e:\Documents\Anthropology\Paper\data-problem.aux) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 10 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 10 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 10 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 10 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 10 was incomplete)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on data-problem.dvi (1 page, 216 bytes).
SyncTeX written on data-problem.synctex.gz
Transcript written on data-problem.log.

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Dec 16 15:33:33
```

This doesn't happen with `\DTLadd{\contribT}{\contribC}{\contribNC}`, though, nor does it happen with:

```
\def\foo{1.2}
\def\bar{3.4}
\DTLaddall{\baz}{\foo,\bar}
```

So I'm at a bit of a loss as to what is going wrong here...

Comment: I am not sure if you are using the `fp` package for calculations but the error seems to come from there. Can you post a minimal?

Comment: @Yiannis: That's what the two files listed above were supposed to *be*; I trimmed out almost everything that I could see was not needed to produce the error... the only things I left that are (presumably) not needed are comments, whitespace, and the third line of the .csv file.

Comment: It seems I read too quickly! Sorry! I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatool doesn't always work perfectly.

In short, your example should work, but my guess is that `\DTLaddall` and `\DTLgaddall` don't like how the `\DTLforeach` loop or the datatool package is making those number. If you use a different macro with a number in it, it seems to work. No matter what I do, I can't make datatool accept a number made from the database.

I know that's not an answer, but I will give you three holiday presents:

1) I've been burned by datatool in the past. It's not remotely bug free, so from my perspective, it's likely a bug.

2) pgf's foreach and math functions can do what you want very easily and you might consider those. You can use datatool to get the csv data and use pgf to walk through it. If you want, I can post an example.

3) I think you already know this, but you can accomplish totaling everything within the database by doing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\def\mynum{0}
\DTLloaddb{contrib}{test.csv}

% add "total" column
%\tracingmacros=1
\DTLforeach{contrib}{\contribD=donor,\contribC=core,\contribNC=noncore}{%
\DTLgadd{\mynum}{\contribNC}{\mynum}
\DTLgadd{\mynum}{\contribC}{\mynum}
%
}

\mynum
\end{document}
```

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if it doesn't. Again, I understand that I'm not answering your question (other than that I think datatool is broken), but hopefully I solved your problem.

Also, btw, the author does make patches and she did fix it for me when I asked her to.

Comment: Really, at this point I was just wondering if it was a bug in the package, or if I had missed something in the manual that would have told me that this kind of thing could happen. So this is good.

Comment: @SamB: Nope. You're smart. For example, if you take the same numbers and store all of them in macros and then use the same `\DTaddall` macro, you won't get an error. No matter what you do, even if you copy those numbers into another macro, you'll get an error. There is something being left behind that is horking `\DTaddall`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a conflict in the marriage between `datatool` and the `fp` package. You can try and use the `fp` package directly (it is loaded by datatool automatically). This works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{contrib}{test.csv}

% add "total" column
%\tracingmacros=1

\DTLforeach{contrib}{\contribC=core,\contribNC=non-core}{%
 \def\a{\contribC}
 \def\b{\contribNC}
 \FPadd{\result}{\a}{\b}
\noindent\result\\
}
\end{document}
```

The `\FPadd` takes three arguments the first of which is a macro to receive the results and the next two the numbers to add. You can use any combination you wish.

Comment: Actually, even `\DTLadd` works -- it's only `\DTLaddall` that fails, and even that only on the loop macros from a `\DTLforeach`. But, er, what are `\a` and `\b` for? I didn't need those with `\DTLadd`...

Comment: @SamB You don't actually need the `\a` or `\b`, they were just shortcuts that I typed as I tried quite a few of the FP commands and didn't want to keep on typing long strings. For example `FPmul` will multiply `FPdiv` divide, there is also a power function.`\FPadd{\result}{\a}{\a}` will totalize. `\result` is defined on the fly, you can use any valid name. `etools` is a great package but it needs some better examples.